# Changing tab indent settings in a particular file (not in the whole application)

Tags: sublimetext3

I know how to change the tab settings in general. But is it possible to change it in a particular file? In my `Sublime`, a `tab` is two spaces. Sometimes, someone modifies a file of mine and when I git pull it the `tab` is now four spaces or whatever.

Can I change it back to my own setting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sublime 3 tabs and spaces do not match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566871/sublime-3-tabs-and-spaces-do-not-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a solution to this in reverse (convert two spaces to four spaces) in response to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566871/sublime-3-tabs-and-spaces-do-not-match).

You should follow the same procedure but in the 3rd step `Tick: Tab Width: 2` instead.