# Automatically convert indentation from 2 to 4 spaces in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, indentation

There are a few topics about auto-conversion of the indentation in Sublime Text, but I didn't find the way to do it automatically.

Many files I download have indentation of 2, which I hate, so I want to convert them to 4. What I do is:

1. Select `Tab size: 2`
2. `Convert indentation to Tabs`
3. Select `Tab size: 4`
4. `Convert indentation to Spaces`

I don't think I need to mention that it's too much work for every single file. Some people suggest `Reindent` option, but for my experience, it almost never works correctly.

Is there some build-it way, or perhaps a package to convert indentation in one step?

Answer (score 2):

Converting indentation to a personal preference can be a tedious task in Sublime Text which, as you observe, gets mentioned on StackOverflow quite regularly. In fact 4 years ago I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40574667/2102457) which lists almost exactly the steps you've listed in your question.

I too have found the 3 *Command Pallette* `reindent` commands to be a little temperamental, sometimes working as I think they ought to and sometimes doing (what appears to be) nothing at all. But no matter...

There is of course a way to perform the actions you've listed in one step; use a macro.

Copy and paste the macro code below and save it in your `User` folder as `IndentationTo4Spaces.sublime-macro`.

```json
[
    { "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "tab_size", "value": 2} },
    { "command": "unexpand_tabs", "args": {"set_translate_tabs": true} },
    { "command": "set_setting", "args": {"setting": "tab_size", "value": 4} },
    { "command": "expand_tabs", "args": {"set_translate_tabs": true} }
]
```

You could run the macro from the menu `Tools --> Macros --> User --> IndentationTo4Spaces`, set up a key binding, or add an entry to the *Command Pallette*.

```json
// Add keys to: Packages/User/Default (Linux/OSX/Windows).sublime-keymap
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+y"], "command": "run_macro_file",
  "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/IndentationTo4Spaces.sublime-macro"} },

// Add command to: Packages/User/Default.sublime-commands
{ "caption": "Convert Indentation To 4 Spaces", "command": "run_macro_file",
  "args": {"file": "res://Packages/User/IndentationTo4Spaces.sublime-macro"} },
```

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't the second one be `"set_translate_tabs": false`?

Comment: I don't think so. The commands in the macro are the ones called by the 4 steps in your list (I used command logging to get them). The macro works perfectly as far as I can tell. Have you tried it?